# What technical steps should I take before publishing my new software?

Tags: vb.net, deployment, visual-studio-2013, release

I am about to publish my first small piece of software. The software is in VB.NET and I have used Visual Studio 2013 as my IDE.

What are the steps I should think about before publishing and do you have any suggestions on how to complete each successfully?

Here is an incomplete list of the steps that I have thought about so far. But I don't know if I may be missing other important steps

- Create an installation package (Status: I have created one using WIX)
- Obfuscate the code (Status: I have obfuscated it using the built-in obfuscator in VS 2013)
- Have a T&C that doesn't make me liable if my software causes problems (Status: I haven't looked into this yet)
- Create a demo and a registration mechanism (Status: I don't know how to do this yet)

Please let me know if my list is pretty complete or if there might be other things that I haven't thought about and that might cause problems for me down the road.

Answer (score 4):

That sounds probably obvious but:

- Try to install/update the software on every supported platform
- Install and test the software on a different machine than your development machine to find dependencies that users may not have
- Ensure that Logging is working as expected and that it gives you the information that you will need to fix issues
- Test how you will fix issues (integrated update, ...)
- List all 3'rd party libraries you have used with their licenses
- Create a Help/FAQ or Documentation
- Figure out how to licence the application and how this behaves when uninstalling etc.

A good list can also be found [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/109249/general-checklist-before-releasing-software).